# wifi not working..kernel update not working

Tags: wifi, kernel, intel

my wifi adapter is **Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168**
and wifi is not working . i searched for my adapter driver on intel site and found this :http://www.intel.in/content/www/in/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html

so according to intel website i need kernel 4.6 atleast to enable my wifi

**what option i tried and failed**

**option1**.
tried to manually update kernel(Linux viking-HP-Pavilion-Notebook 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) using commands
wget http://in4serv.com.br/backup/kernel-4.6.2
sudo chmod +x kernel-4.6.2
./kernel-4.6.2

it installed the kernel but i am unable get it running ..even tried the advanced boot option .system was still running 4.4 kernel

**option2 :**
used ukuu kernel udate utility and installed latest kernels successfully but not able to get anyone of them running .system still boots using 4.4 kernel.
the advanced boot option does not shows the latest installed kernel

**option3:** 
downloaded the driver firmware files from intel website (iwlwifi-3168-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz) and tried to copy it to /lib/firmware but unable to do so..

so i am stuck with 4.4 kernel and unable to install driver so wifi is not working

**any help is highly appreciated** as i wasted lots of hours to get it work but of no use..

Comment: Have you installed another Linux distro since installing EOS?

Comment: Take a look at https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11958/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-update-from-elementary-os-loki-0-4-to-loki-0-4-1

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal window

```
sudo apt install linux-image-extra-virtual-hwe-16.04
```

Comment: run the command but of no benift ..kernel running still 4.4 and wifi still not working..but can u tell what this command did?

Comment: Was there any output? What did happen? It is a kernel update, you have to restart computer after to run the new kernel.

Comment: I restarted ..yes it updated the kernel but systems is Still running on 4.4 kernel ..
Problem is I am able to install new kernels but elementary is still running on 4.4 ..I tried to Boot in advance option also but there also it's showing only 4.4 kernel not newly installed kernel

Comment: Hold down the right shift key while booting and select the kernel. If it is not available, it was not really installed, you should try again and if there are any errors copy them here so that someone might help